# Re-arrange an array with nested object (JS)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I receive the following response of activities from a datasource. These have unique start times, and can belong to the same product.

Currently the Product Information object is nested within the activity. I have tried unsuccessfully to "re-arrange" and group the information.

The structure I require is to have a Product (productCode) with activities with the same product code in object within the Product.
 eg.
"productCode":"PTFTVD"
"activities":[{activity 1, activity 2 etc}]

```
 var activities = [  
   {  
  "id":39170350,
  "productCode":"PTFTVD",
  "startTime":"2017-09-06T00:00:00Z",
  "endTime":"2017-09-06T05:30:00Z",
  "startTimeLocal":"2017-09-06 10:00:00",
  "endTimeLocal":"2017-09-06 15:30:00",
  "product":{  
     "productCode":"PTFTVD",
     "productType":"DAYTOUR",
     "name":"01 Koala & River Cruise - Return cruise with Entry into Lone Pine",
     "shortDescription":"The Koala and River Cruise is a memorable"
  }
   },
{  
  "id":41498876,
  "productCode":"PJIOQO",
  "startTime":"2017-09-06T04:15:00Z",
  "discount":{  
     "id":7,
     "title":"Discount Rulezzz"
  },
  "product":{  
     "productCode":"PJIOQO",
     "productType":"CUSTOM",
     "name":"1 Hour 15 Minute Segway Joy Ride Experience",
     "shortDescription":"Tour Length 14km  approx. "
  }
   },
  {  
  "id":41498757,
  "productCode":"PJIOQO",
  "startTime":"2017-09-07T04:15:00Z",
  "product":{  
     "productCode":"PJIOQO",
     "productType":"CUSTOM",
     "name":"1 Hour 15 Minute Segway Joy Ride Experience",
     "shortDescription":"Tour Length 14km  approx. Almost non stop segway r…nd we custom make this tour to "
  }
   },
   {  
  "id":41498846,
  "productCode":"PJIOQO",
  "startTime":"2017-09-08T04:15:00Z",
  "product":{  
     "productCode":"PJIOQO",
     "productType":"CUSTOM",
     "name":"1 Hour 15 Minute Segway Joy Ride Experience",
     "shortDescription":"Tour Length 14km  approx. Almost non stop segway r…nd we custom"
  }
   },
   {  
  "id":41498600,
  "productCode":"PJIOQO",
  "startTime":"2017-09-09T04:15:00Z",
  "product":{  
     "productCode":"PJIOQO",
     "productType":"CUSTOM",
     "name":"1 Hour 15 Minute Segway Joy Ride Experience",
     "shortDescription":"Tour Length 14km  approx. Almost non stop segway r…nd we custom make this tour t"
  }
   }
]
```

Comment: great, what does not work? please add your code as well.

Comment: Start by using the _.groupBy function in Lodash on product code, that should get you started, it will give you an object like `{"PJIOQO": [products], ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically a switching of data is grouped in two stages:

1. Group the product,
2. Collect activities for a product.

For 1, you need a searchable data structure, like an object or a `Map`, where you have a key and data collected.

Here, you could use the `productCode` as key and take the data of `product` as new values. Add then a property for collecting the activities.

Use an array for the result set and push a new product to the result set, while the product is still accessable with the key in the object.

Now go to 2. and collect all data and assign it to the activities array.

Voila!

```js
var activities = [{ id: 39170350, productCode: "PTFTVD", startTime: "2017-09-06T00:00:00Z", endTime: "2017-09-06T05:30:00Z", startTimeLocal: "2017-09-06 10:00:00", endTimeLocal: "2017-09-06 15:30:00", product: { productCode: "PTFTVD", productType: "DAYTOUR", name: "01 Koala & River Cruise - Return cruise with Entry into Lone Pine", shortDescription: "The Koala and River Cruise is a memorable" } }, { id: 41498876, productCode: "PJIOQO", startTime: "2017-09-06T04:15:00Z", discount: { id: 7, title: "Discount Rulezzz" }, product: { productCode: "PJIOQO", productType: "CUSTOM", name: "1 Hour 15 Minute Segway Joy Ride Experience", shortDescription: "Tour Length 14km  approx. " } }, { id: 41498757, productCode: "PJIOQO", startTime: "2017-09-07T04:15:00Z", product: { productCode: "PJIOQO", productType: "CUSTOM", name: "1 Hour 15 Minute Segway Joy Ride Experience", shortDescription: "Tour Length 14km  approx. Almost non stop segway r…nd we custom make this tour to " } }, { id: 41498846, productCode: "PJIOQO", startTime: "2017-09-08T04:15:00Z", product: { productCode: "PJIOQO", productType: "CUSTOM", name: "1 Hour 15 Minute Segway Joy Ride Experience", shortDescription: "Tour Length 14km  approx. Almost non stop segway r…nd we custom" } }, { id: 41498600, productCode: "PJIOQO", startTime: "2017-09-09T04:15:00Z", product: { productCode: "PJIOQO", productType: "CUSTOM", name: "1 Hour 15 Minute Segway Joy Ride Experience", shortDescription: "Tour Length 14km  approx. Almost non stop segway r…nd we custom make this tour t" } }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    products = [];

activities.forEach(function (a) {
    var temp = {},
        key = a.product.productCode;
    if (!hash[key]) {
        hash[key] = {};
        Object.keys(a.product).forEach(function (k) {
            hash[key][k] = a.product[k];
        });
        products.push(hash[key]);
        hash[key].activities = [];
    }
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k !== 'product') {
            temp[k] = a[k];
        }
    });
    hash[key].activities.push(temp);
});

console.log(products);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works fine with the sample data. However I run into a stumbling block earlier on.

To create the list of array of Activities I am using this.Activities.push(session);

where session is an individual activity.  I need to do this as we filter out other sessions

When a run the above, the above solution is empty.  Am I pushing the session into the wrong thing?

Comment: with the data, i can only guess, what you mean. what is `this.Activities` and what is `session`?

Comment: We do an API call get an array of Activities which we call `activityResults`

 We then have logic that loops through the `activityResults` and apply our own logic and the ones that meet our conditions we push to the `activities`

We have something along the lines of

`activities = [];

for (var x=0; x < activityResults.length; x++){
 // then an if condition, and if condition is met we push to
 this.activities.push(activtyResults[x]);
}`

Comment: this is what is logged in console for console.log(products)

[ ]
length: 0__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: are you working with async? is the data actually not given?

Comment: I figured out the issue by moving the code you provided. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6 you could do the following

```
 ....
 //activities already defined
 let projectToActivityObject = {}
 activities.forEach((activity) => {
    let productID = activity.product.productCode;
    projectToActivityObject[productID] = projectToActivityObject.hasOwnProperty(productID) ? projectToActivityObject[productID] : new Set();
    projectToActivityObject[productID].add(activity);
 });
 console.log(projectToActivityObject);
```